# What does the git command below do?

Tags: git

I unstand the `git checkout -b new_branch` indeed. But what's the meaning of this?

```
git checkout -b mac_dev origin/mac_dev
```

Answer (score 2):

`git checkout -b ＜new-branch＞ ＜existing-branch＞`

*By default git checkout -b will base the new-branch off the current HEAD. An optional additional branch parameter can be passed to git checkout. In the above example, ＜existing-branch＞ is passed which then bases new-branch off of existing-branch instead of the current HEAD.*

In this case, a new branch name <mac_dev> is created based on the existing branch <origin/mac_dev> which I presume this branch is reside in the cloud repository.

References:

[1] https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-checkout

Comment: Would like to add here that if `mac_dev` exists locally, you'll receive an error when trying to create the branch. However, if it does not exist locally, then it'll essentially be equivalent to `git checkout mac_dev`.